# Are Python integers reference types?

Tags: python, types, reference, integer

We all know that lists in Python are reference types i.e a variable holding a list doesn't hold the list directly, but rather holds a reference to it.

And we all know even the fact that everything in Python is an object.

So the question that comes in my mind is that integers are also objects in Python and so variables holding integers would also contain references to the integers; then why are only lists classified as reference types?

**Aren't integers in Python also reference types following from the fact that everything is an object in Python?**

Comment: There's no such thing as a reference type in Python. Types are types, and every name is a reference to *some* object

Comment: So why do we say that lists are stored by reference and integers are stored by value?

Comment: *You* might say that; I certainly don't. The distinction simply does not exist in Python. All objects, whether of type `int` or `list`, just *are*, and we refer to them using names. There is no fundamental difference between `x = 3` and `x = [3]`; in both cases, `x` refers to a value of some type (`int` in the former, `list` in the latter).

Comment: Read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: If you want to call a list a reference type, then yes, `int` is a reference type as well, just like *every other type* in Python. The term "reference type" has no meaning in Python when there are no other kinds of types to contrast it against.

Comment: @chepner that sounds convincing. So lists are stored as pointers to the lists and integers are also stored as pointers to the integers. Right?

Comment: Not really; that's an *implementation* detail of CPython, not something that matters to Python's data model. Both `list` and `int` objects are opaque blobs that "exist" *somewhere*, and the only access you have to an object is some name or other reference (but not "reference" in the C++ sense).

Comment: @chepner the resource you provided a link to is useful!

Comment: *"why are only lists classified as reference types"* - Who said that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These concepts don't really apply in Python. In my experience "reference type" and "value type" are mostly used in .NET languages such as C#, where they have specific meanings - variables of a reference type store a reference to an object, while variables of a value type store the value of the object directly. You can't obtain a reference to that object stored in the variable (although you may be able to create a "boxed" copy of that value and obtain references to the box). The terms may be used by analogy in other languages - but for example in Java *all* classes would be what .NET considers "reference types" and only primitives behave as "value types" do in .NET, so there the terms aren't really as necessary. So let's return to Python.

If we use the .NET meaning, then *yes,* all Python types are effectively "reference" types, in that every variable is a reference* to an object and doing `a = b` will make `a` refer to the same object as `b`. However, the thing about "reference types" and "value types" is that when an object is *immutable* it no longer really *matters* whether it's of a reference type or a value type. You can't do the one big thing where the distinction matters - you can't have two references to the same object, modify the object through one of them and then be surprised when the other changes!

This is a long-winded way to say that when people call integers "value types" in Python they are probably *thinking* about them in terms of C# or maybe Java, and observing that they behave much the same as value types do in C# or primitives do in Java, because they do! But that's really because they're immutable more than anything else.

---

* Here I'm using "reference" in a more general sense than the specific one found in C#. The general sense is of some kind of handle, address or identifier that specifies a particular object, such that we can have many of these "references" to a single object. Both "reference" and "pointer" are general terms that may have more specific meanings in certain languages. For example a C# reference is a very similar concept to a Java reference, but rather different from a C++ reference. In some languages a "pointer" is specifically a numeric memory address that you can manipulate with arithmetic, in other languages it is indistinguishable from the general sense I described for "reference". I find the term "reference" to be the most neutral and most useful to describe what we have in Python, but be careful with all these terms when comparing one language to another.

Comment: so when people say integers are "value types" in Python, it's technically wrong. Rather they are immutable reference types. Right?

Comment: More or less, yes. It depends on how you reinterpret the term "value type" for Python. You could make a reasonable case that it's a nonsensical statement, rather than an incorrect one.

Comment: But again, you simply aren't going to use the term "reference type" when talking about Python. It doesn't make sense to qualify the term "type" when there is only one kind to talk about in the first place. It would be more accurate to say something like "Python's data model has value semantics closer to C++/C#'s reference types than to its value types."

Comment: Also, the distinction between reference type and value type is more important when variables themselves have types. In Python, only *values* have types; a variable is just a name that can refer to any type whatsoever. In `x = z; y = x`, the value of `y` cannot change based on the type of value you assign to `x` next.

Comment: Heh, I almost made the exact same point - that all this matters more when you need to worry about the types of variables (and indeed expressions) separate from the types of values. But I decided the answer was too deep in the weeds already!

Comment: @chepner Your `y` *can* change if let's say `z = globals()` :-P

Comment: @superbrain No, because that would require something other than a simple assignment to the *name* `x`, like `x['y'] = ...`.

Comment: @Weeble I'd say the possibility to check object identity is another significant difference between immutable reference and value types. For example CPython has optimizations when you try to combine a `frozenset` with itself, and I've written/seen identity checks in algorithms as well (admittedly usually with mutable types, but it would apply to immutable ones as well).

Comment: @chepner [see for yourself](https://repl.it/repls/AnguishedWorthwhileProject#main.py)

Comment: Eh, yeah, OK, that's a weird corner case because the namespace is a first-class object. (I'm also not entirely sure how much of a guarantee Python provides that assigning to `globals()` will actually affect the global n namespace.) But yeah, probably not a great example.

Comment: @chepner Can you name one language where variables also have types, since I am relatively new to programming in general.

Comment: @superbrain `globals()` returns a dictionary, so `z` is a dictionary thus so is `y`. Dictionaries are mutable.  Changes to a mutable object are unsurprising.

Comment: C, Java, C++, C# Go, Pascal, ... *Most* languages have the type associated with the variable.

Comment: OK, I just got it! *int x = 10* in Java means that x has type *int*. But in Python, *x = 10* doesn't mean that way. This is because every variable is an object. Right?

Comment: @coderboy right.  In Java you can't turn around and go `x = "hello"` on the next line, but in Python you can because `x` doesn't have a type.

Comment: @MarkRansom Actually [you can](https://repl.it/repls/ImperfectAliveOutcome#Main.java) :-P

Comment: @MarkRansom that's perfect! So Java variables have types, but this is not the case with Python. In Python only values have types - all variables have an *object type*.

Comment: @superbrain OK that was cheating.  I should have said `x = "hello";`.

Comment: Why can't you have two references to an immutable object? You write: "you can't have two references to the same object, modify the object through one of them and then be surprised when the other changes!" Well, but the other one is immutable, so what can really happen?

Comment: You can have two references to an immutable object. That sentence is trying to say "you can't { have two references to one object AND modify the object via one of those references AND observe the change via the second reference }". I thought it was clear enough in context but I will think about rewording it.